# Is it possible to reuse a databricks jobs cluster in different jobs to avoid start up times for 2nd job?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Is it possible to reuse a databricks jobs cluster in a 2nd job if it has just been freed up by a first job -  to avoid start up/ wait times for the 2nd job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A jobs cluster is tied to a job.

Alternatives:

- Use [a pool](https://docs.databricks.com/en/compute/pools.html). Could not find pricing details.

  - Create a pool.
  - Edit the jobs cluster configurations to use said pool in instance type drop down.
- Use an all-purpose cluster. Costs a lot more than a jobs cluster.
- Convert your jobs to tasks and consolidate within one job. Tasks within a job can reuse running jobs cluster. Obviously you'll have to write some convoluted code, and I would really recommend against this option.